# Smart Paging: can it work with custom view mode (other than full)?

Tags: paging, display-suite, entities

Relevant modules: Smart Paging 7.x-2.1 and Display Suite 7.x-2.2.

Pagination works for `full` view mode but it doesn't work for my custom view mode which I set through `hook_entity_view_mode_alter` in `template.php`. I am using a custom view mode for article on another theme.

How can I make Smart Paging work for my custom view mode?

Thanks!